# What is meant by the term "program" which appears in the sentence of stage production

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> We plan to use photographs of our performers in full costume for the posters and programs.

This quote is from sentences of the certain stage production.

What "program" does it be meant?

I think that photos are not used in stage play so I am guessing that program here means "video program" for advertisement(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/program) offers this definition of **program**

> a brief usually printed outline of the order to be followed, of the features to be presented, and the persons participating (as in a public performance)

I don't know about other countries, but in the US, a program for a stage production is a small booklet that might contain a lot of interesting information about the show, the performers, and the production staff. If the show is presented by school children, it will likely be very short—1 or 2 photocopied pages. If the show is professionally produced, it might be 100+ glossy pages that include photos. It might even include advertisements.

Comment: The same in British English (only we would spell it _programme_!). Usually audience members can buy a copy on their way in, or a simple one may be distributed free.